# How to apply Multiple filter on single column of grid in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

For Example, I am Having Grid [image]

Can I apply Different type of Filter on Single column ?

Comment: I think you cannot set multiple filter type on a column. You will have to develop this feature by yourself.

Comment: OK.! Then I need to find some alternative.

Comment: in fact it is not this hard to extend the header menu. You can add items in this header in the event `headertriggerclick`

Comment: Let me give a try with your option.

Comment: Ok let me know if you need more help and share your solution if you succeed. I think a lot of people would like to add this feature in their grids ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not this simple but you can add items in the header menu with the event `headertriggerclick`. Then you can add your custom functionality that add another filter in it.

```
this.on('headertriggerclick', function(ct) {
    var grid = ct.grid;
    var menu = ct.getMenu();

    menu.items // Add custom items here, you can copy the existing filter item (should be the last one)
});
```